# Modules (Theorem,Claim,Proof etc) LyX Question

Tags: lyx

I have a question about LyX. When I use for example Proof, I write stuff, but in the middle of the proof I have to prove another lemma. So I click Lemma, but it ''closes'' the proof. I don't really know the right word to explain it. I want to use Lemma in the Proof, but I want the Proof thing continue. Can someone explain me how I can do that? I hope my question was clear. I don't really know the terms for these things. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the cursor in the Lemma environment and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. When you finish with the Lemma, add a `separator` (also from the modules), and finish the proof.

## LyX screenshot

[image]

## Output

[image]

Comment: I don't use LyX, but just to know: is it possible to edit the source code (as HTML editors does)?

Comment: @Sigur: AFAIK, while it's possible to *view* and even *export* the source code, one cannot edit it directly in LyX, unless the whole document is entered using LaTeX codes in the ERT (evil red text) mode. But even then, it's tricky to change stuff in the preamble. One of the advantages of using LyX is its WYSIWYM interface, which provides visual *approximation* of the output. It would defeat such a purpose to type up the whole document in ERT. I guess that's the cost for WYSIWYM `:)`